# Dark lines around div which is positioned above an image with the same width

Tags: css

I have a card with a background image. There is a div within this card with its width set to `100%` but you can still slightly see the background image on either side of the div. I have removed the `box-shadow` so that you can see the issue better.

```css
/*This is the main card*/
.card
{
    width:              465px;
    height:             700px;
    display:            inline-block; 
    position:           relative;
    /*box-shadow:       3px 3px 5px #D5D5D5;*/
    border-radius:      15px;
}

/*This assigns the background image to the card*/
.card:nth-Child(1)
{
    margin-right:       30px;   
    background-size:    100%;
    background-image:   url('images/daniel-malikyar-F1leFzugQfM- 
    unsplash.jpg');
}

/*This is the rectangular div positioned at the bottom of the card*/
.cardContentContainer
{
    width:              100%;
    height:             350px;
    bottom:             0;
    overflow:           hidden;
    position:           absolute;                  
    background-color:   white;
    border-bottom-left-radius:  15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

I tried giving the content container a `1px` white border but the lines are still visible.

[image]

REQUESTED PEN: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/voKMGG

Comment: Also would be nice to have some codepen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't repeat border-radius. This is the reason for these artifacts.

```
.card
{
    ...
    border-radius:      15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And remove `border-radius-*` from `.cardContentContainer`

Also remove `left: 50%` and `transform`

https://codepen.io/vovchisko/pen/gVMyRW

Comment: Thanks so much, that fixed it. The transform was left there from when the div did not take up 100% of the width. I wonder why centering the div created those artifacts.Thanks again.

Comment: @MarkusMulholland because transform do exactly what you want - move left 50%. But your block with was 465px / 232.5px, and makes 0.5px artifacts.

Comment: But using -50% within translate and left: 50% should just center it.

Comment: Left:50% would floors i guess, transform not. Not sure about anything this days :3